# What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?

Tags: java, terminal, console, console-application, gnu-screen

I would like to write a Java terminal application that does screen manipulation. Are there any good libraries out there that allow you to manipulate the screen like curses in the *nix/C world?

Minimal features I'm looking for are windowing and user input support.

In feature-speak, I'd like to have a region of the terminal where some data is regularly updated while (at the same time) the user can enter commands/text in some other part of the screen.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/), which links to native code but has an api based on Swing.
The [screenshots](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Screenshots.html) show lots of text windows, so that looks useful.

Comment: Nice one, too bad though that it requires native libraries. I'll give this a shot and see how far I get.

Comment: Last release: 2006.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Just updating...Last release: 2013.

Comment: @BartSchuller The link is dead.

Answer (score 65):

## Lanterna

I found the [*Lanterna*](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) library recently.  Haven't had the opportunity to use it yet but it looks like a more up-to-date alternative to the others.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for one that uses no native code.

Comment: Last update was 4 months ago.  Seems like the most recently maintained solution here.

Comment: [*Griffon*](http://griffon-framework.org/) is an application framework that supports 4 different UI toolkits: Swing, JavaFX, Apache Pivot, and Lanterna.

Answer (score 26):

Haven't used it myself, but [Java Curses Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses) sounds like what you want.

Comment: Sounds good, but I think I'll go with Charva, since that'll provide a more OO experience. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Java Curses last release: 2002.

Comment: Java Curses has now gotten some recent attention, and a new release in 2012.

Comment: Java Curses last release: 2012-12-07

Comment: Last Update: 2015-08-07. Note that this uses native code.

Answer (score 10):

[Here](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2008/01/java-native-interface-jni-notebook.html) is a way to call the ncurses lib using JNI.  I tested this and it works.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2013, the closest I can find is [Blacken](https://code.google.com/p/blacken/).

Blacken is not a curses library per-se. It moves away from the terminal, and instead, renders it's own "console window." This has the disadvantage of not looking "console-like." Instead, you get full (arbitrary) colour support, and a curses-like API (in addition to their main API).

You can also set the font to `Mono` for fixed-width characters.

Comment: Perfect for what I was wanting to do. Thank you.

Comment: @jdersen there are some bugs in Blacken, but overall, it's quite good, and the owner responds quite quickly to opened issues.

Comment: Last release: Sep 27, 2012