# Pretty printing using java for unix console

Tags: java, linux, pretty-print

I'm writing a small server designed to handle just a few clients. For every connection the server starts a new thread and does some work.

I want to be able to print information about what the server is doing, seperated in columns so that you can see what information belongs to a specific thread/client.

Something like this:

```
thread 1              thread 2                   thread 3
-----------------------------------------------------------
task 1                 task 7                     task 2
[====>    ] 50%        ops! something happend     task 2.1
                                                  task 3
```

So I want to be able to update, remove or add a line in each column during runtime. Is there any libs out there that I can use? It does only have to work in linux terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either find an [ncurses library for java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321308) or get real familiar with [terminal escapes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php).