# How to print a character in an x,y coordinate in the console using kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, console

I want achieve that to make a basic game

Is there any way to print a character in console in a `x,y` coordinate like `gotoxy` function in conio library of C language?

Comment: Your best bet is to use ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as with C, Java provides no built-in way to do full-screen terminal output.

And, as with C, you have two main options:

- You could assume that the terminal understands [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), and output those directly.  That's quick-and-dirty; it doesn't require any dependencies, and the basics can be done fairly easily.  But it's not very maintainable; anything more sophisticated gets very fiddly — and, more importantly, it's likely to fail on other terminal types.
- Or you could use a library which does all the hard work.  [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321308/whats-the-best-way-to-get-text-user-interfaces-ncurses-like-functionality-in) ask about that, and have several answers.