# Trying the delete lines individually and clear the console

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, console

I need to clear the console, for both windows and Linux, though Mac would be helpful.

I also need to delete the latest individual line.

I looked through multiple forums and none of them worked...
Can someone please show something that actually works?? Rather then marking as duplicate.

I tried these to clear the screen:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls"); // and "clear" too 

System.out.flush(); 

private final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";

System.out.print('\u000C');

System.out.println("\f");

final static String ESC = "\033[";
System.out.print(ESC + "2J");
```

But none of these seem to work.. Do I need to add a special library like LWJGL to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888362/commands-in-java-to-clear-the-screen

Comment: None of those work.. What am i missing