# How to animate multiple command lines?

Tags: java, animation, command-line, console, output

I wonder how to animate multiple lines, like what Docker does. I'm hoping for a Java or C++ example, but I don't think it matters with ANSI.

```
macbook: bill$ docker pull jenkins
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/jenkins
55cbf04beb70: Downloading  457.4kB/45.31MB
1607093a898c: Downloading  572.6kB/10.74MB
9a8ea045c926: Downloading  621.7kB/4.336MB
d4eee24d4dac: Waiting 
c58988e753d7: Waiting
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221/how-to-animate-the-command-line) only handles one line. As does this [other well-known question/anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852665/command-line-progress-bar-in-java). [Clearing the screen and returning home](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440270/4513509) doesn't seem to work either, because is seems newlines remain regardless of flushing, using the clear screen character, or using the home character.

Comment: Do some research into things like [curses](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=curses+api&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  Just beware, Java's console handling is pretty primitive. It's hard to know, but something like [fusesource/jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) might work

Comment: Also, read the `tput` man page