# Override previous Console Output

Tags: java, console

is it possible to override the last `System.out.println` output, so i can for example visualize changes in a array or create a progessbar?

For example if i have this class:

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        System.out.print("#");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

What do i have to do to create this simple progressbar which is shown in a single line and not in 10 seperate lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on my particular console (Windows) but it's not terribly portable...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("#");
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.print("\r                    \r");
            }
            System.out.flush();
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

There's also the [`Console`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class, but that doesn't actually buy you very much as far as I can see...

Comment: thanks! it works under linux too, can i also use this to clear multiple lines?

Comment: @reox: No, it's just using `\r` to go back to the start of the line, then writing a load of spaces, then going back to the start of the line again. You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications) for more elaborate control.

Comment: okay, maybe i'll use a jframe with textarea instead :D thank you!