# How to write a console application that only update the upper part only in Java?

Tags: java, console

There are two parts of my console programme, part A, and part B
[image]

Part A will keep updating, for example, some loading progress, and part B is the menu, or some rarely update part. I print the whole UI using `System.out.println`

So, instead of update the whole screen using `System.out.println` to keep refreshing the screen. Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications