# How to Clear Console in Java?

Tags: java, console

I have been pulling my hair for this since quite long time. I have researched for an hour on how to clear a console in Java.

All I found was dirty hacking either by printing a bunch of lines or executing this

```
Runtime.getruntime.exec("cls/clear");
```

However, nothing seems to be working for me. Isn't there really any a way of clearing the console in Java like in C (`clrscr();`). Isn't there any external library by which this can be achieved.

Please let me know if anyone has ever done this before using a proper function, library etc. instead of dirty hacking.

Comment: 'like C'? I think the only way to do that in C is to use a library like ncurses. If that's what you're after, this question describes how to get similar/identical results with Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications.

Comment: If you have a VT100 Terminal maybe you could use Escape Codes (Esc[2J Clear entire screen ED2) see http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php For other Terminals there could be other escape codes. The eclipse console doesn't except any escape code.

Comment: Similar question: **[Java: Clear the console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)**

Answer (score 28):

If your terminal supports [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), this clears the screen and moves the cursor to the first row, first column:

```
System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
System.out.flush();
```

This works on almost all UNIX terminals and terminal emulators. The Windows `cmd.exe` does not interprete ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 8):

Try this code

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class CLS {
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    }
}
```

Now when the Java process is connected to a console, it will clear the console.

Answer (score 3):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("PlatformDepedentCode");
```

You need to replace "PlatformDependentCode" with your platform's clear console command.

The `exec()` method executes the command you entered as the argument, just as if it is entered in the console.

In Windows you would write it as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");`.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");` doesn't work (all the times) on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

---

```
System.out.println("\f");
```

---

'**\f**' is an *escape sequence* which represents **FormFeed**. This is what I have used in my projects to clear the console. This is simpler than the other codes, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct the console to clear.

For serial terminals this was typically done through so called "escape sequences", where notably the [vt100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) set has become very commonly supported (and its close ANSI-cousin).

Windows has traditionally not supported such sequences "out-of-the-box" but relied on API-calls to do these things.  For DOS-based versions of Windows, however, the ANSI.SYS driver could be installed to provide such support.

So if you are under Windows, you need to interact with the appropriate Windows API.  I do not believe the standard Java runtime library contains code to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement clrscr() using simple for loop printing "\b".

Answer (score -2):

If you are using windows and are interested in clearing the screen before running the program, you can compile the file call it from a .bat file.
for example:

---

cls

java "what ever the name of the compiles class is"

---

Save as "etc".bat and then running by calling it in the command prompt or double clicking the file

Comment: if your approach is used then it clears everything before launching program but the question is about clearing screen at runtime when java program is running.