# After running a loop, how do I clear the screen so each loop shows up on a blank console?

Tags: java, console, console-application

// It is horse racing and the loop is looping the horses position a little further each time it loops. Without clearing the screen it just shows the previous position before each new position and it looks sloppy. I am trying to clear the old positions before running the new positions

Comment: It sounds like you are using the console...if so, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console

Comment: If you're on Unix, you might also want to check out [ANSI escape codes as mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10241217/56285). Or then just go with a [good Java library for console apps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/439799/56285).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which OS you are:

- On windows, you can clear using: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls" );`
- On Unix: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear")`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using console. You can execute `cls` or `clear` commands from your code by doing as follows. This is system dependent.

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls"); //Windows
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear"); //Linux
```