# Is it possible to recall a println in Java?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Say I am making a command-line interface. I want to print out a string, and then change it. For example, when you run the program, it prints out

```
Hello, World!
```

A few seconds later, though, the message gets changed to:

```
Hello, Computer User!
```

Is this possible? Cross-OS would be preferable.

Comment: Look up "curses" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications

Comment: @pst - curses isn't exactly cross-OS.

Comment: @TedHopp But an equivalent Java implementation is (or is as much as can be expected) - the link I added was found via `[java] curses` quite trivially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could echo the `\b` escape sequence, which is backspace, and then write out a new message, in place of the old-one.

Do note, this might not be completely cross-platform, as it is upto the console itself and how it interprets `\b`, but it should work mostly.

Comment: I did not know this existed. Thank you so much. I'm going to go try this now.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
    String s1 = "Hello, word!";
    System.out.print(s1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print('\b');
    }
    System.out.print("Hello, computer user");
```

note that it does not work from Eclipse, run it from command line