# Have static lines in console

Tags: java, ssh, console

I am wondering how to in Java set up the console so the first couple lines in the console will always be there and contain info about the program. So for example I would want the progam to display the first line in the console as:
JavaProgram Version: 0.5b

and even if the console spams new lines that line will stay at the top. Another good example would be how cgminer shows the most relevant data at the top.

My initial approach for tackling this issue would be to create a loop that every tick send enough lines to exactly fill the console size; however, I do not know if it is possible to get the console height.

Any help would be awesome!
Thank you,
    Kyle

Comment: This seems to more about the console functionality than about Java.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what the [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) family of libraries is all about; so I'd use [Java Curses Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/),

Comment: Does Cruses work in pure console/ server environments. Will it still work if I SSH into the program?

Comment: @UnleashurGeek `Curses`, and yes it should work (as long as your `TERM` is correct).