# Console program for making time appear on the same position

Tags: java, multithreading, datetime

I'm trying to write a *console* program to display the current time recursively on the same line and position.

I tried a lot but it is getting printed in multiple line using normal `System.out.println`, so I used `PrintStream` object. Now the thing is that it is appearing in the same position, but not getting updated.

I couldn't be sure whether problem is with thread or `PrintStream`. Please help me with this problem or is there any other method to make things appear recursively on the same position in a console app?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;

public class DateDemo {

  // boolean flag=true;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    DisplayTime dt=new DisplayTime();
    Thread thread1=new Thread(dt,"MyThread");
    //thread1.start();
    thread1.run();
  }
}


class DisplayTime extends Thread {
  public void run() {  
    try {
      while(true){
        showTime();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
      System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public void showTime(){
    try {
      PrintStream original = new PrintStream(System.out);

      // replace the System.out, here I redirect to 
      System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("stdout.log")));

      // System.out.println("bar");  // no output
      Date date =new Date();
      original.print(date.toString());
      // System.out.println(date.toString());
      
      System.out.flush();
      // output to stdout
      // original.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
      System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: first of all, use Thread.start() instead of Thread.run() to execute a thread.

Comment: yes, you are write Sanjeev calling Thread.run() will execute run() method in the same thread, without starting new thread. So use Thread.start() instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First your title is misleading, please read what [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) means.

What you need to do is to override the curret line with the new time. This is done in a console programm by using the the carriage return charcter `\r` (to go back one character you can use the backspace character `\b`)

You could try something like this (Note that for this to work you must not print a new line charachter `\n` at the end of your line ):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Time {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        while(true) {
            System.out.printf("\r%s", sdf.format(new Date()));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to delete a number of chars from the current line ((char)8)  :

```
public class Time {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Date now = new Date();
            System.out.print(now.toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            for (int i = 0; i < now.toString().length(); i++) {
                System.out.print((char) 8);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But like A4L's answer, this won't work in every console, i.e. Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem with system.out.println() was that it printed always another line then just try using system.out.print() and after printing just give it a system.out.print(\n) or system.print.out.println()

Comment: actually the concept is to print in the same position and not on the same line

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library before, but I think it *should* give you what you want. Basically the java equivalent of old skool curses library for terminal applications.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Another fellow on stackoverflow mentioned lanterna -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896503/3465651