# Change size of font System.out.println

Tags: java, fonts, size, println

Can you tell me how to increase the size of the font using System.out.println in java.

Comment: There's no "font" for `System.out.println`. Are you talking about the output of some console? Like Eclipse?

Comment: You may need to use ncurses instead of System.out, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications

Answer (score 5):

There is no concept of "font" with `System.out`.

Edit the console font settings for whatever application you're using as an output console.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through coding as in the font size is based on your console. 
I assumed you use eclipse to code your java code. So, you can change eclipse console font size here.
General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts

Which you can get the source here.
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is a console output. Unfortunately there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change fonts for Java output. See details here:

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/06/change-font-in-output-window-in.html