# How to Replace a String to Output Different Text Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My issue is wanting to replace the content of a String with another String. For example, if I have the word Generating Code.., then after waiting two seconds, I want the program to replace Generating Code with Generating Code Successful.

*** Note that I am using Eclipse, and the following code works for Notepad ***

```
String code = "Generating code...\r";

String successful = code.replaceAll(code, "Generating the code has been successful.\r");

[...]

try {
       System.out.print(code); // prints out Generating Code
       Thread.sleep(2000); // Waits two seconds
       System.out.print(successful); // Replaces Generating Code with has been successful
    }
```

This code works in Notepad because the \r replaces the text. However, in Eclipse \r does not replace the text, and instead ends the line. Is there a way of getting this functionality to work in Eclipse?

My code in Eclipse is identical to that listed here that works in Notepad++.

Comment: `\r` doesn't replace the text, it is a carriage return. This looks like a difference in how the two consoles handle carriage returns.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936

Comment: Would you know the equivalent of \r functionality in Notepad++ for Eclipse?

Comment: Try googling for "eclipse console carriage return".

Comment: So apparently there is a bug in Eclipse that prevents this from happening. However, the article you submitted suggested that this was fixed, so I assumed it could have an alternative way.

Comment: The last few (quite recent) comments describe a regression.

Comment: You want `replace`. `replaceAll` takes a regular expression. Also, use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) instead of `'\r'`.

Comment: How about a C++ equivalent, is it possible to use system("cls"); to clear the screen in Java Eclipse and call the methods again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch He doesn't want the line separator. He explicitly wants `\r` to move the curser back to the start of the same line the write something else (in this case *"Generating the code has been successful."*).

Comment: @tom carriage return doesn't do that on any tty I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Since I never used that (sounds like a big code smell to me :D), I can't tell on which tty that works, but this is what OP wants :D. He wants to replace a printed line with another one.

Comment: @tom I guess he wants a java curses library.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want such a functionality to work in eclipse console??? Normally, you and your developers will be the only people using eclipse to run the code... No???

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Then this question might help: [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/439799) (too bad it is off-topic and eligible for closing)