# implementing KeyListener code, Java. Not recognising input

Tags: java, keylistener

My aim is to do something when I press an arrow key. But it's not recognising any input.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


class keyb extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    public keyb(){

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("alsfhkasld");
        keyb ff = new keyb();

        System.out.println("end");
        System.out.println("ennnn");

    }


    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("anything....");
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            System.out.println("up! UP!");
        }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            //y+=50;
        }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){            
            //x+=50;
        }else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_B){
            System.out.println("B come on!");
        }

    }
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e){}

}
```

There are no errors when I compile. It just ignores any key I press.
If this is something to do with JFrame, for example it only works for GUI, could someone please suggest another way to read the arrow keys as input?

Comment: do you want to recognize arrow key press in console ??

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener` only works in a GUI. If you don't want to be like everybody else and create a GUI you will need to use a library that sets the terminal into non-canonical mode and provides some abstraction over the events. The exact details will depend on the library you end up picking, and probably your operating system too. See for example [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

Answer (score 1):

When you actually show the JFrame by setting `setVisible(true)`, it will work

```
public keyb(){

    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);

    setVisible(true);

}
```

*(By the way, as per java naming conventions, classes start with an upper case)*

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is incomplete. you can follow below code to implement keylister.

> import java.awt.*; import java.awt.event.*; import javax.swing.*;
>
> public class KeyChecker extends JFrame {
>       JLabel keyLabel = new JLabel("Hit any key");
>
> ```
> public KeyChecker() {
>     super("Hit a Key");
>     setSize(300, 200);
>     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>     setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
>     KeyMonitor monitor = new KeyMonitor(this);
>     setFocusable(true);
>     addKeyListener(monitor);
>     add(keyLabel);
>     setVisible(true);
> }
>
> public static void main(String[] arguments) {
>     new KeyChecker();
> } }
> ```
>
> class KeyMonitor extends KeyAdapter {
>       KeyChecker display;
>
> ```
> KeyMonitor(KeyChecker display) {
>     this.display = display;
> }
>
> public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
>     display.keyLabel.setText("" + event.getKeyChar());
>     display.repaint();
> } }
> ```