# Scala - functions to output to screen/console - clear, position, set color

Tags: scala, curses

I am looking for a basic set of functions to be mixed with Scala standard output commands.

These commands should:

- Clear the screen
- GoTo cursor position X,Y.
- Change the color of the text.

I am in the strange situation of trying to explain why this is not a duplicate question after already explaining so in the comments. Forgive me for the duplication.

There are two fundamental differences in the two questions. First I am not looking for full curses functionality, second I am looking for interoperability with the Scala IO. Laterna, probably the best answer fails miserably in the second aspect.

I suspect the best answer is a library which calls curses, since such a library is likely to interoperate with Scala IO. That question does not ask for a library which calls curses it asks for curses-like functionality.

Comment: What exactly are you missing? You already seem to want to use curses, based on the tags. So what is your actual problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

Comment: @Thomas Dickey, not quite. I'm asking for libraries that play well with basic Scala IO. That is not something that was asked in that question. I've already  laterna and it fails miserably. Possibly because the Scala IO does not work well with curses, but more likely that laterna does not use curses.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey also I am not asking for full curses capability, just some basic functionality.

Comment: i'm interested in knowing the answer to this question.  I was going to try java-curses, curious to know what you did