# Java: Screen like Implementation for commandline

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java application that runs multiple threads where most of them produce unique output that can't and shouldn't be mixed with the output of other's.
In a nutshell I'm wondering if there is anything available that allows me to "switch" inbetween the output of the different threads. For example "Press x to navigate to the output of the next thread"

The linux screen command is basically what comes close to this.
Needs to work in commandline so no swing available.

Any input is highly appreciated.
If not it would end up in a custom build....

Comment: If it's only about viewing logs then the (currently only) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486766/6730571) would be your best option. If the actual need is more involved than that, and you wand to build a text-based GUI, check out [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) or [other suggestions discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439799/6730571).

Comment: Lanterna or the other suggestions you liked comes close to what I was looking for. would vote this one as correct answer.

Comment: Alright, posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only about viewing logs then  [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486766/6730571) would be your best option.

If the actual need is more involved than that, and you wand to build a text-based GUI, check out [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) or [other suggestions discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439799/6730571).

Answer (score 0):

Write the output to separate log files. Now you can `tail -f` whichever log file you want to view. You can even open multiple command windows and tail multiple logs in parallel.