# Difference in Processing of System.err.print and System.out.print

Tags: java, system.out, system.err

Is there a differnece how System.err.print and System.out.print are processed while getting executed?
I have a twodimensional array of Integers ranged between 2 and 20. The Array is printed as a Matrix and all Integers >=10 shall be printed red, using System.err.print. 
If doing so the output looks like this:

```
 7   11  15  12  12  12  11  16  17  17  13   4   7 
 9    8   4 
 9  
 9    4  10 
12    4  16  12  10
```

with all int>=10 being red.
instead of looking like this

```
 11   7   4  15   7 
  9  12   8  12   4 
  9  12  11  16  17 
 17   9   4  13  10 
 12   4  16  12  10
```

without the red marks i want.

Both use the same array, first gets printed with this code:

```
public static void printArray2(int ar[][]) {
    if (ar == null)
        System.exit(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
            if (ar[i][j] < 10)
                System.out.print("  " + ar[i][j] + "\t");
            else
                System.err.print(" " + ar[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

while the second output gets printed with this code

```
public static void printArray(int ar[][]) {
    if (ar == null)
        System.exit(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ar[i].length; j++) {
            if (ar[i][j] < 10)
                System.out.print("  " + ar[i][j] + "\t");
            else
                System.out.print(" " + ar[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Is there way to prevent the unformmated output while still using System.err.print?

Comment: GhostCat's answer is good, but if you don't want to use a third-party dependency: `final String red = "\u001b[31m"; final String reset = "\u001b[m"; System.out.println (red + "This prints in red" + reset)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically those two streams represent **different** consoles.

What really happens when you print to them might very much depend on the JVM implementation or the underlying operating system.

In that sense: your real problem is your assumption that you can use the consoles like this.

The purpose of the error console is: you print important error messages there. As an alternative approach - check out if you can use some "ncurses" like library for your application (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications) as starting point). In other words: instead of mis-using stderr like this - look into ways to gain more control over stdout. So that you can print in colours on one *console*, instead of two.