# Printing in a specific location

Tags: java

How can I make Java print a string variable in a specific position on the screen, preferably using x/y coordinates? Not printing a specific piece of text (although this would be useful) but printing a variable, such as a name that the user enters.

Comment: You would need to use a curses-like library. https://stackoverflow.com/q/439799/3788176

Comment: Look for ansi escape sequences