# How to column break in java

Tags: java

**Expected Output**

```
Enter exam score:             Enter grade:
Math:                         Math:
Science:                      Science:
History:                      History:
```

How to get  this output?

**My output**

```
Enter exam score:                
Math:                                     
Science:                                        
History:

Enter Grade:
Math:
Science:                                                        
History:
```

How do I enter input in the next column?

Comment: You need to fix up the formatting so that people can understand what you are really asking.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sorry, mistyped. I edit already 

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for `System.out.printf()` where you can use %- to add padding to your strings to make them even when printing. You can adjust the exact amount of spacing by changing the 30, but this should work for you:

```java
String mathStr = "Math:";
String scienceStr = "Science:";
String historyStr = "History:";
System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", "Enter exam score:", "Enter grade:");
System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", mathStr, mathStr);
System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", scienceStr, scienceStr);
System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", historyStr, historyStr);
```

**Edit:** Added variables to show OP it works with those as well.

Comment: How to column " Enter the Grade"

Comment: O instead of using System.out.println() use System.out.print() and add `\t` tab characters as needed

Comment: @maryannfernandez Sorry didn't understand what you wanted to do at first. Try it now.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. Can i use printf if the statement have variables

Comment: @maryannfernandez Yes essentially how the printf works is the first string parameter is the formatting. %s corresponds to String, %d to Integer, %f to Float, etc. So if you had `printf("%s%d", strVar, intVar)` that would print out your strVar and intVar with no spaces in between. Notice that the parameter order matches the % order. The 30 in `"%-30s"` sets the padding (and the - I believe just specifies starting from the left) so a 10 character String would have 20 spaces after it.

Comment: @maryannfernandez The line `System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", "Math:", "Math:");` could easily be replaced with: `String mathStr = "Math:"; ` `System.out.printf("%-30s%s\n", mathStr, mathStr);`

Comment: System.out.print( "Math: ");
int HW= Integer.parseInt(num.readLine());
System.out.print("Science: ");
int AT= Integer.parseInt(num.readLine());
System.out.print("History: ");
int BE= Integer.parseInt(num.readLine());
double res=(HW+AT+BE+)/3;
double perc = res*.25;

Comment: If you want to print integers with it you have to use %d instead of %s. And the number of % signs in the first parameter to `printf()` should match the number of parameters after.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I think you want to provide a way for the user to enter the data in a columnar display on a console.

That is difficult.  The problem is that when the terminal driver is in normal ("cooked") mode, the console only accepts the user's input and sends it to your program when the user types ENTER.  And that causes the console display driver to go to the next line.

To solve this, you have to do one of the following:

- Find a 3rd party Java library that directly supports columnar display layouts.
- Find a 3rd party Java library that allows you to put the terminal driver into "raw" mode and move the input cursor around the console window.  Read this Q&A for some suggestions:

  - [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

But I would recommend that you don't do this.  If you want a "fancy" input screen for your users to enter input, implement it in Swing, or JavaFX, or using a web (HTML + CSS + Javascript) interface.  If you need to accept input from the console, make it look like this:

```
Enter exam score (0-100) followed by a grade (A-F):
Math: 99 A
Science: 88 B  
History: 21 F
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first  activity in my Java subject.