# Async Streams with print in command line

Tags: java

I'm writing a command line application. I have list of strings, which are currently executed synchronously. I would like to make the execution a bit faster, so I was thinking about `CompletableFuture`. It solves my problem, but only partially.
In the time of execution I want print the process in the command line, something like this:

```
> Executing str1... <State>
> Executing str2... <State>
...
> Executing str3... <State>
```

Where `State` is updated after `CompletableFuture` is done.

Currently I have:

```
List<String> strs = someInput();

strs.forEach(str -> execute(str));
```

and:

```
private void execute(String str) {
    System.out.format("> Executing %s...", str);

    Optional<State> stateOptional = heavyTask(str);

    stateOptional.ifPresentOrElse(s -> System.out.format("%s%n", s.getState()), 
                                  () -> System.out.format("%s%n", State.FAILED.getState()));
}
```

And `State`:

```
enum State {
   DONE, FAILED;
...
}
```

I'm not sure, how to add the `CompletableFuture` so the console output remains correct. I have tried adding the `parallelStream()`, but the output is messy.

Comment: Elaborate on "output remains correct". Where is it currently wrong?

Comment: Currently I'm not sure how to change the state in command line, after completablefuture is done.

Comment: You mean you want to override `<State>` in the command line? Not print each whole line again with the corresponding changed `<State>`?

Comment: You need your output in a queue like `0,1,2,3,....N`, or `0,2,3,1...N` is OK ?

Comment: @akuzminykh yes, I want to replace the <State> in the command line.

Comment: @VictorGubin yes, it would be nice to persist the order of strings.

Comment: Ok, seems like you are looking for terminal (curses) library - see. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications i.e. [javacurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) 2. As well as you can output all tasks at once, and then exact asynchronous task  will simply replace their status.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve my goal without curses?

Comment: You could somehow clear the terminal and re-print everything with any new information

Comment: @OneCricketeer I was thinking about doing so, then I would have to restructure the codebase a bit, but it should work. But I don't know how to clean and print in the same line, without breaking others.

Comment: It would depend on the terminal, usually, but you'd have to clear the whole "screen"... One way to work around that would be store a list of lines/objects you always want printed

Comment: @OneCricketeer is that efficient?

Comment: Probably not, but it's the only way I can think to ensure ordering of async actions within a terminal window

Comment: @Forin your code should be cross-platform, or only a specific OS needed i.e. just Windows, Mac or Linux or all of them together ?

Comment: @VictorGubin the best would be to make it work under all platforms, but firstly I'm focused on Linux