# How to Split Console into parts in Java?

Tags: java, console

I'm making a simple java Main application, I want to split the console screen into two parts and every part will print an individual output independently!

Actually I do not want to manipulate the screen! I just want to have two parts for printing the results!

Comment: Your q is not clear, you using Swing GUI, to show Frame separated to 2 panels, each one will contain the console log prints ?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good Java, curses-like, library for terminal applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799/whats-a-good-java-curses-like-library-for-terminal-applications)

Comment: I'm making a simple java Main application! there no GUI! but need to display the result in two terminal or multi part terminal!