# Is it possible to print an element at every index until it reaches the end?

Tags: java, arrays

I have been learning about arrays and an interesting question popped up in my head.

I was wondering that with the current Java version, is there a way for me to print a character `string n` and make it appear for a brief moment at every index of an array consisting of only `""`, and then towards the end of the array, it can stop when it reaches the end index of the array.

For example if here is the given array and `string n = "2"` :

```
[2,"","","",""]
```

the code will continously update like

```
["2","","","",""]
["","2","","",""]
["","","2","",""]
["","","","2",""]
["","","","","2"]
```

and the end result would be

```
["","","","","2"]
```

I would like to see the whole movement of `"2"` being played out without printing any excess arrays ( no more than one array should be in the output).

Is this possible? If yes, can you please suggest what should I look over to learn how to do this?

Comment: In java you can not have arrays of different datatypes (in this case int and String). You could however have the 2 be in a string so ["2","","","",""] or [String.valueOf(n), "","","",""]. If I then I understood your question correctly, to make the "2" move across you just need to swap values. So index 0 is swapped with index 1, then 1 with 2 etc, until you are at the end.

Comment: I meant "string n". Sorry for the confusion. Also, would your approach display the movement of the string "2" though. I would like to know if that is possible in Java.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do simple animations, but it depends on the capabilities of the terminal / console you are writing the output to.  Leads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439799 and google for "ansi escape codes" .

Comment: For simple one-line animations you may be able to use a combination of "backspace" and "carriage return" characters to overwrite the current line.  (It depends on the console's behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Java but you won't be able to do it reliably within all consoles or terminals. You can however do it reliably if you utilize a GUI mechanism like a JOptionPane or JDialog and display that during console operation, for example:

[image]

The above example is a JDialog. Below is the code (read comments within):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class AnimatedMoveArrayElementDemo {

    /* Default. The length of the Array to animate.
       Can be changed via command-line (/L:n) argument.   */
    private int lengthOfArray = 8;
    
    /* Default. The Array value to move from beginning to end.
       Can be changed via command-line (/N:n) argument.   */
    private int arrayValueToMove = 2;
    
    /* In Milliseconds (1000 = 1 Second).
       Can be changed via command-line (/S:n) argument.   */
    private int animationSpeed = 1000;
    
    /* Default. The dialog display font size.
       Can be changed via command-line (/F:n) argument.   */
   private int displayFontSize = 24;
    
    private String[] stringArray = {}; 
    int arrayIndex = 0;

    Timer animationTimer;
    JButton startButton;
    JLabel arrayLabel;

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // App started this way to avoid the need for statics
        new AnimatedMoveArrayElementDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            readCommandLineArguments(args);
        }
        
        fillArray();
        createAndShowDialog();
    }

    private void createAndShowDialog() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Moving Array Element To The End Position");
        dialog.setBackground(Color.white);
        dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setModal(true);

        arrayLabel = new JLabel();
        resetDisplayLabel();
        arrayLabel.setOpaque(false);
        arrayLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        arrayLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        arrayLabel.setFont(new Font(arrayLabel.getFont().getFamily(), 
                                    arrayLabel.getFont().getStyle(), displayFontSize));
        dialog.add(arrayLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        int calculatedWidth = getStringPixelWidth(arrayLabel.getFont(), 
                                      arrayLabel.getText().replaceAll("<.+?>", "")) + 50;
        int calculatedHeight = getStringPixelHeight(arrayLabel.getFont(), 
                                      arrayLabel.getText().replaceAll("<.+?>", "")) + 100;
        dialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(calculatedWidth, calculatedHeight));
        
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
        startButton = new JButton("Start Animation");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start Animation"))  {
                    if (arrayIndex > stringArray.length - 1) {
                        resetDisplayLabel();
                        arrayIndex = 0;
                    }
                    startButton.setActionCommand("Stop Animation");
                    // Using a Swing Timer...for animation
                    ActionListener performTask = new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            arrayIndex++;
                            if (arrayIndex > stringArray.length - 1) {
                                animationTimer.stop();
                                startButton.setText("Restart Animation");
                                startButton.setActionCommand("Start Animation");
                                return;
                            }
                            stringArray[arrayIndex - 1] = "\"\"";
                            stringArray[arrayIndex] = String.valueOf(arrayValueToMove);
                            String arrayString = "<html>" + Arrays.toString(stringArray) + "</html>";
                            arrayString = arrayString.replace(String.valueOf(arrayValueToMove),
                                    "\"<font color=red>" + String.valueOf(arrayValueToMove)
                                    + "</font>\"");
                            arrayLabel.setText(arrayString);
                        }
                    };
                    animationTimer = new Timer(animationSpeed, performTask);
                    animationTimer.start();
                    startButton.setText("Stop Animation");
                }
                else {
                    animationTimer.stop();
                    startButton.setText("Start Animation");
                    startButton.setActionCommand("Start Animation");
                }
            }

        });
        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        dialog.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        });
        
    }
    
    private void fillArray() {
        stringArray = new String[lengthOfArray];
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                stringArray[i] = "\"" + arrayValueToMove + "\"";
            }
            else {
                stringArray[i] = "\"\"";
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void resetDisplayLabel() {
        fillArray();
        String arrayString = "<html>" + Arrays.toString(stringArray) + "</html>";
        arrayString = arrayString.replace(String.valueOf(arrayValueToMove),
                "<font color=red>" + String.valueOf(arrayValueToMove)
                + "</font>");
        
        arrayLabel.setText(arrayString);
    }

    /**
     * This application can currently accept four specific integer command-line 
     * arguments prefixed with a specific Command related to that argument.
     * 
     * @param args (Command-Line varArgs [optional])<pre>
     * 
     *   Length Of Array:     The length (# of elements) of the String[] Array 
     *                        to animate. The longer the array the smaller the
     *    Command: /L         font size you <u>may</u> want to use so to fit the array
     *                        into the display window. The display window will 
     *                        automatically size itself to try and accommodate 
     *                        the array length. The default is 8.
     *                      
     *                        Examples of acceptable command-line commands for 
     *                        this argument are: /L{value}, /L:{value}, etc.
     *                        Basically, The command can be anything as long as 
     *                        it starts with /L (or /l) and contains no spaces
     *                        or digit(s). Digits are reserved for the actual 
     *                        argument value passed along with the command, for
     *                        example: /L:8 (/L: 8 is not acceptable) or you 
     *                        could use: /Length=8. Anything can be between the
     *                        /L and the integer argument value. Either will tell 
     *                        the application the the length of the Array to 
     *                        display will contain 8 elements. No whitespaces 
     *                        are permitted within a Command-Line Command.
     *                     
     *   Array Value To Move: This would be the integer value that is placed 
     *                        within the first element of the String Array at
     *       Command: /N      index 0. The default value is: <b>2</b> however
     *                        you can change this value to whatever you like.
     * 
     *                        Examples of acceptable command-line commands for 
     *                        this argument are: /N{value}, /N:{value}, etc.
     *                        Basically, The command can be anything as long as 
     *                        it starts with /N (or /n) and contains no spaces
     *                        or digit(s). Digits are reserved for the actual 
     *                        argument value passed along with the command, for
     *                        example: /N:8 (/N: 8 is not acceptable) or you 
     *                        could use: /Number=8. Anything can be between the
     *                        /N and the integer argument value. Either will tell 
     *                        the application the the number within the Array to 
     *                        display will be the number 8. No whitespaces are
     *                        permitted within a Command-Line Command.
     *  
     *   Animation Speed:     Default is a value of 1000 milliseconds which is
     *                        basically equivalent to 1 second. You can set the 
     *     Command: /S        animation speed to whatever you like but do keep
     *                        in mind that you could set a speed that will be so
     *                        fast that you can't tell there is any animation.
     * 
     *                        The value passed with this command would be an 
     *                        integer value representing Milliseconds.
     * 
     *                        Examples of acceptable command-line commands for 
     *                        this argument are: /S{value}, /S:{value}, etc.
     *                        Basically, The command can be anything as long as 
     *                        it starts with /S (or /s) and contains no spaces
     *                        or digit(s). Digits are reserved for the actual 
     *                        argument value passed along with the command, for
     *                        example: /S:800 (/S: 800 is not acceptable) or you 
     *                        could use: /Speed=800. Anything can be between the
     *                        /S and the integer argument value. Either will tell 
     *                        the application that the animation speed for the 
     *                        Array display will be 800ms. No whitespaces are
     *                        permitted within a Command-Line Command.
     * 
     *   Display Font Size:   Default is a font size of 24 but any font size can
     *                        be used to display the Animation and the display 
     *      Command: /F       window will automatically size accordingly.
     * 
     *                        Examples of acceptable command-line commands for 
     *                        this argument are: /F{value}, /F:{value}, etc.
     *                        Basically, The command can be anything as long as 
     *                        it starts with /F (or /f) and contains no spaces
     *                        or digit(s). Digits are reserved for the actual 
     *                        argument value passed along with the command, for
     *                        example: /F:36 (/F: 36 is not acceptable) or you 
     *                        could use: /Font=36. Anything can be between the
     *                        /F and the integer argument value. Either will tell 
     *                        the application that the animation Font size for the 
     *                        Array display will be 36pt. No whitespaces are allowed
     *                        within a Command-Line Command.</pre>
     */
    private void readCommandLineArguments(String[] args) {
        String command = "";
        int value;
        for (String arg : args) {
            // Split Alpha and Numeric.
            String[] argParts = arg.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
            command = argParts[0].substring(0, 2);
            value = 0;
            if (argParts.length == 2) { 
                value = Integer.parseInt(argParts[1]);
            }
            switch (command.toUpperCase()) {
                case "/L":
                    this.lengthOfArray = value;
                    break;
                case "/N":
                    this.arrayValueToMove = value;
                    break;
                case "/S":
                    this.animationSpeed = value;
                    break;
                case "/F":
                    this.displayFontSize = value;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println("Unknown Command-Line Argument!");
            }
        } 
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the pixel width of the supplied String.<br>
     * 
     * @param font (Font) The String Font to base calculations from.<br>
     * 
     * @param characterString (String) The string to get the pixel width for.<br>
     * 
     * @return (int) The pixel width of the supplied String.
     */
    public int getStringPixelWidth(Font font, String characterString) {
        FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        };
        Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(characterString, null);
        return (int) bounds.getWidth();
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the pixel height of the supplied String.<br>
     * 
     * @param font (Font) The String Font to base calculations from.<br>
     * 
     * @param characterString (String) The string to get the pixel height for.<br>
     * 
     * @return (int) The pixel height of the supplied String.
     */
    public int getStringPixelHeight(Font font, String characterString) {
        FontMetrics metrics = new FontMetrics(font) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        };
        Rectangle2D bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(characterString, null);
        return (int) bounds.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String n = "2";
        String array[] = new String[10];
        Arrays.fill(array, "");
        array[0] = n;
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        while(i < array.length-1){
            // swap 
            String temp = array[i+1];
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response. I was however wondering that would it be possible to show the movement in one single array only. Like maybe let 2 appear at index 0 for a second and then move 2 to index 1, showing it for a second and so on, sort of like an animation... I'm not sure if this is possible in Java or not, which is why I asked.

Comment: To animate that you would need to do it within a dialog or window of some kind other than the console window.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like the following:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    annimate("2");
}

private static void annimate(String uniqueElement) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] array = new String[]{"2", "", "", "", ""};
    int uniqueElemIndex = 0;

    while (uniqueElemIndex < array.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].equals(uniqueElement)) {
                uniqueElemIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (uniqueElemIndex + 1 < array.length) {
            String elem = array[uniqueElemIndex];
            array[uniqueElemIndex + 1] = elem;
            array[uniqueElemIndex] = "";
        }
        uniqueElemIndex++;
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
[2, , , , ]
[, 2, , , ]
[, , 2, , ]
[, , , 2, ]
[, , , , 2]
```